# Sorting special character strings in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have got a list of strings that contain special characters.

For example:

> ["Geben", "Zurück", "Über", "Äpfel"]

I need to sort this list in Kotlin to have the following output:

> Ascending: ["Äpfel", "Geben", "Über", "Zurück"]

> Descending: ["Zurück", "Über", "Geben", "Äpfel"]

How to do this?

Edit:
Using `sortedBy` gives the following output which is not desired:

> ["Geben", "Zurück", "Äpfel", "Über"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a collator that recognizes German umlauts:

```
fun Iterable<String>.sortedWithUmlauts() =
    sortedWith(Collator.getInstance(Locale("de", "DE")))
```

Comment: Is there any way, this can be done generically, for instance if the list contains strings of German as well as French language?

Answer (score 1):

As every language has its own sorting rules there is no sorting for two languages "out of the box". But as experimented myself even the German collator instance gave good result for a list of mixed French German words. Moreover you can set the strength property of the collator control the sort algorithm - dependent on which results you expect.